# installing dependency for python package in pip3 install xxx

Tags: python, pip

Does anybody know how pip3 install is working? , what is the order of the steps executed? Are the dependencies installed prior the package stuff is copied out of the package?

I have created python package and put it on Pypi server. it has a lot of dependencies from which one is the netFilterQueue. As my project is using Python3.4
and netfilterQueue works for Python2.7 , i wrote my code to install it in the setup.py. It basically change the path to the prepared and patched version of netfilterqueue and tries to run its setup.py. 
So the stuff under nfq/NetfilterQueue-0.3.1-P3.3 is that one and is included in the package. 
Specifically it looks like this( added some print command to check what is wrong with it):

```
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
nfq_dir = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'nfq', 'NetfilterQueue-0.3.1-P3.3')
for f in listdir(parent_dir):
    print("package item:", f)
try:
    if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'):
          python = 'python'       # virtualenv install
    else:
          python = 'python3.4'    # normal install
    os.chdir(nfq_dir)
    subprocess.check_call([python, 'setup.py', 'install'])
    os.chdir(parent_dir)
```

When I download the package from Pypi manually and unzip it and i try to install it using sudo python3.4 setup.py install,
it works fine. 
The problem is when I use sudo pip3 install Mypackage.

It ends up with the error message ( result of the executed code mentioned above):

```
error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip_build_root/Mypackage'
```

NetfilterQueue directory:

```
/tmp/pip_build_root/Mypackage/nfq/NetfilterQueue-0.3.1-P3.3
```

I supposed the parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(**file**))
is the rifht place where the setup.py is actually running from.
but perhaps I am wrong.

Can anybody some light on it and help to solve it?

Comment: Why don't you make the patched NFQ a separate dependency, from a specific repository, rather than distribute it with the package? That makes it easier to use it with other projects, too.

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to do it regarding NFQ is not my code

Comment: Then why do you think you're allowed to do it how you're *currently* trying to do it? I'd expect the license allows you to do both or neither. Have you checked how it's licensed and what that allows?

Comment: anyway i wonder why listdir(parent_dir) complains about the parent_dir when parent_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)) shold provide the path to the actually running python  modul, right?

Comment: i have probabl;y found an answer to this issue here : http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PythonEggs#accessing-package-resources